# Android system recovery from Windows

Tags: recovery-mode, system, system-apps

I have the cheap Android tablet. During my experiments, I had rooted it and removed application folder. Now I can't turn on my tablet it is loading forever.

I have read about ways to load new ROM on my phone. Most of them start from uploading some apps on phone. I can't do it.

Also, I tried adb tool. But command: `adb devices` don't see my device.

Is it possible to recover Android system in some if Android OS isn't started and adb tool doesn't see the device?

Comment: What android device is that? what model? Please give all information

Comment: Loading​ new OS doesn't involve install ''some app'', you probably misunderstood what you read.  ADB can't ''see'' your device simply because it's not booted and eventually USB debugging is not enabled.

Comment: it is a cheap no-name device. I guess I need universal ROM for recovery.

Comment: As I get correct, I removed system apps and it is reason why I can't boot device.

Comment: Simply flashing a firmware/ROM may solve the problem. That's why we need some informations about the device

Comment: @esQmo_ I tried to recover the system from recovery menu (up and power buttons were pressed) without success. Could you point what I have to do?

Comment: You can't recover any data by factory reset since you deleted the system folder! Just flash your device using a computer! Tell the model of the device otherwise I can't help you further

Comment: @esQmo_ Sorry, for long delay I had the problem with getting a model of my device.  It is somytec M08T2 - http://somytec.gmc.globalmarket.com/products/details/exw-price-8-inch-quad-core-mtk8127-wifi-tablet-pc-m08t2-9286616.html .

Comment: For this phone you need a SP Flashtool and flash files.

Comment: @esQmo_ pls, write it as an answer, I will be able to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting system folders can brick your device. That's what happened. Some files are part of the booting process and since they are not present the system can't go further. To be able to boot normally again, you'll need to flash the firmware/ROM for this model.

ADB can't find the phone on this state because android needs to completely boot for USB Debugging to be operational.

As this phone is a *Mediatek* device, you'll need **SP Flashtool** as the flasher software and flashing files need contain a scatter file which is a sort of phone internal chip memory "map".  Also you need MTK drivers to allow the phone be detected.

You can find thousands of video tutorials on how to flash a Mediatek device using [SP Flashtool](http://spflashtool.com). Flash files can be found on [Needrom](http://needrom.com)